# Subtracting a string from a string in a Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
    date item1 item2  item1 birth  item2 birth  item1 age  item2 age
0   1980     a     f         1975         1979          5          1
1   1980     a     f         1975         1979          5          1
2   1979     e     f         1979         1979          0          0
3   1979     e     f         1979         1979          0          0
4   1978     c     d         1976         1978          2          0
5   1977     a     b         1975         1975          2          2
6   1977     a     b         1975         1975          2          2
7   1975     a     b         1975         1975          0          0
8   1975     a     b         1975         1975          0          0
9   1977     b     a         1975         1975          2          2
10  1976     b     c         1975         1976          1          0

[11 rows x 7 columns]
```

When doing this:
`df2 = df[ df['date' - 'item1 birth'] <= 3 ]`

I get this:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

When instead going:
`int('date') - int('item1 birth')`

I get this:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'date'`

And when doing:
`float('date') - float('item1 birth')`

I end up with:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: date`

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you change the dtypes: `df['date'] = df['date'].astype(int)` and `df['item1 birth'] = df['item1 birth'].astype(int)` and then perform `df2 = df[(df['date'] - df['item1 birth'] <=3)]` does it work?

Comment: Think of this in terms of the order of operations, like you would in maths. You have `'date' - 'item1 birth'` inside a pair of brackets, so that gets evaluated first, which means Python has to try to subtract a string from a string, which doesn't work anywhere in Python.

Comment: @EdChum: Yes, you are right. It works as desired after changing the dtypes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column values of numeric dtype, you could subtract the column values this way:

```
mask = (df['date'] - df['item1 birth'] <= 3)
df2 = df.loc[mask]
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for suggesting this solution. It works perfectly, and doing it like this there is no need for changing dtypes.